# How to build an array from a table using MatLAB script?

Tags: matlab, matrix, datatable, multi-index

I am trying to pick a specific array from a table of m*n data using MatLAB.
**Error Message: Index exceeds than matrix dimensions**

Check the below MatLAB script:

```
    t_res = 0.2;
    c_angle = 360/30;
    iact = 0.1;
    V = 12;
    p = 1;
    
    for p=1:length(p),
    for p=1:5,
        Time = p*t_res;
        Angle = Time*c_angle/2;
        if (p == 1)
            delt_i = 0; 
        else
            delt_i = 0.5* t_res* V /L_obt;
        end
     iact = iact+delt_i;
    
     [~, ~, raw] = xlsread('F:\User\Matlab\data1.xlsx','Sheet3','A2:D11');
     data = reshape([raw{:}],size(raw)); 
     Current = data(:,1);
     Angle1 = data(:,2);
     Torque = data(:,3);
     Fluxlinkage = data(:,4);
     
    
     F = scatteredInterpolant(Current,Angle1,Fluxlinkage);
     Fluxlinkage = F(iact,Angle);
     L_obt = Fluxlinkage/iact; 
     F = scatteredInterpolant(Current,Angle1,Torque);
     Torque = F(iact,Angle);
    
    
    Table = [p' Time' Angle' iact' delt_i' abs(Torque)' Fluxlinkage' L_obt'];
    fprintf('%d\t\t %f\t\t %f\t\t %f\t\t %f\t\t %f\t\t %f\t\t %f\n', Table');
    
    end
    p=p+1;
    Table(3,5);
    end
```

Getting an error message: **Attempted to access Table(3,5); index out of bounds because size(Table)=[1,8]**

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should at least say where the error occurs.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `p` as the loop variable for both loops when they are nested... and you don't need `p=p+1` since the point of the for loop is no manual incrementation! Looks like you should just remove the outer for loop. Aside from that, don't read the same Excel data every loop, just do that outside the loop! This code really makes no sense without context, and could likely be greatly improved with context...

Comment: I've removed the outer loop as well as p=p+1. Still the same error as "Attempted to access Table(3,5); index out of bounds because size(Table)=[1,8].".

Comment: @Wolfie pls do vote this question which can help me to ask questions as its blocked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in line 11 you say:

```
delt_i = 0.5* t_res* V /L_obt;
```

But `L_obt` doesn't seem to be defined.

Then, you have a problem with the instruction at line 38:

```
Table(3,5);
```

Since `Table` is a one dimensional array (one line of 8 values), you only need one number, between  1 and 8, for example `Table(3)` or `Table(5)`. In a case of two dimensional arrays, `Table(3,5)` would mean that you want the value in the 3rd line and 5th column.

Comment: The value in 3rd row and 5th column.

Comment: That's right @PradeeptaSahu. Does this answer your initial question? Feel free to vote and accept in that case :-)

Comment: @ alpereira7
pls do vote my question so that I can able to ask questions. Now my account is banned.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a restructured version of your code.  I moved the stuff that doesn't need to be in the loop out of it.  And made some assumptions about what you really were trying to do.  See comments below for explanation of the changes.  Note: I can't test this since I don't have your spreadsheet but it should at least get you closer.

```
t_res = 0.2;
c_angle = 360/30;
iact = 0.1;
V = 12;
%p = 1;  %This does nothing since your iterate over p in the loop

%These things don't depend n "p" so don't put them in the loop
[~, ~, raw] = xlsread('F:\Pradeep\Matlab\data1.xlsx','Sheet3','A2:D11');
data = reshape([raw{:}],size(raw));
Current = data(:,1);
Angle1 = data(:,2);
Torque = data(:,3);
Fluxlinkage = data(:,4);
F1 = scatteredInterpolant(Current,Angle1,Fluxlinkage);
F2 = scatteredInterpolant(Current,Angle1,Torque);

%I assume you want to build your var "Table" in the loop ... not to be
%confused with an actaul Matlab type "table" ... so pre-allocate
Table = zeros(5,8);

for p=1:5,
    Time = p*t_res;
    Angle = Time*c_angle/2;
    if (p == 1)
        delt_i = 0;
    else
        delt_i = 0.5* t_res* V /L_obt;   
    end
    iact = iact+delt_i;

    Fluxlinkage = F1(iact,Angle);
    L_obt = Fluxlinkage/iact;
    Torque = F2(iact,Angle);    

    %You were just overwritning the same row again and again ... so create
    %a new row for each results.
    Table(p,:) = [p Time Angle iact delt_i abs(Torque) Fluxlinkage L_obt];
    %Print the new row.
    fprintf('%d\t\t %f\t\t %f\t\t %f\t\t %f\t\t %f\t\t %f\t\t %f\n', Table(p,:));

end
%Not sure what this is for ... since the output is surpressed by the
%semi-colon ???
Table(3,5);
```

Comment: I'm trying to pick an array like if i should select a generated table value for 3rd row and 4th column it automatically give the specific value. Trying to plot any 3 variables from the same generated table.

Comment: Like I said in the code comments you were overwriting the same row in your table on each iteration of the loop.  Now it should build your `Table` matrix correctly.   If you want to see what is in the 3rd row 4th Column then you would use value = Table(3,4).   However, the way you have it above `Table(3,5);`  will put that particular value into the default `ans` var but suppress the output to the command prompt ... so basically it does nothing.

Comment: If for example you wanted to plot  angle vs time  The you would do something like this:  `plot(Table(:,2),Table(:,3))`   But only if you fix your code like in my example to actually build the Table and not overwrite it.

Comment: I am trying to plot a surface between time, angle, torque.

Comment: How to make a surface using the above script?

Comment: As it is now you can't.  You don't have enough points and I don't think it would make any sense.  Ex. You would need a Torque value for every time & angle combination.  time(1) & a(1,2,3,...), time(2) & a(1,2,3...) , ... etc.  So Torque would need to be size nxn.  You could do a 3-d plot  plot3(time, angle, torque) ... but it might make more sense to do a series of subplot(3,1,1);plot(time,angle), subplot(3,1,2);plot(time,torque), subplot(3,1,3);plot(angle,torque)

Comment: Torque values can be obtained from interpolation method using time and angle values and it's mentioned in code.

Comment: @ Aero Engy pls do vote my question so that I can able to ask questions. Now my account is banned. I would be grateful if you can help.